# Inserting class of clicked element and ID of parent into another image

Tags: javascript

I'm a JavaScript novice and I'm having some difficulty getting my code to work. I've set up a function that pulls in variables based on element classes and IDs and executes it onclick.

```
<div id="holder">
    <img id="wallImg" src="/testpath/selwall/nopaint.jpg">
</div>

<div id="options">
    <ul id="selWall">
        <li class="bluepaint" onclick="printStuff()"><strong>Blue</strong></li>
        <li class="redpaint" onclick="printStuff()"><strong>Red</strong></li>
        <li class="greenpaint" onclick="printStuff()"><strong>Green</strong></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function printStuff() {

        var imgCategory = srcElement.parentNode;
        var imgClass = srcElement.className;

        document.getElementById("wallImg").src="http://testurl.co.uk/media/gbu0/" + imgCategory + ImgClass + ".png";

    }

</script>
```

The user is supposed to be able to select their paint colour from a selection of swatches (the ul#selWall li elements) and the JS will change the source of a particular image ID on the page (in this case, img#wallImg) with the clicked element's class and clicked element's parent element ID.

Eventually I want to be able to expand this script to use the ul id as a URL parameter name and the paint type (i.e. `testurl.com/paint-selection&selWall=bluepaint&selDoor=greenpaint`.) As far as I know, JQuery is unable to append URLs so I'd rather stick with plain JavaScript.

Comment: I was under the impression that it was an alternative for the target - i.e. what you've clicked on - but for Internet Explorer, which I'd like to maintain compatibility for.

Sorry if that's incorrect...

Comment: If the solution will be provided in jQuery then is it ok for you ?

Comment: Yes, a JQuery solution would be better as I'm more attuned to it. I wasn't aware I could achieve the results I wanted with JQuery however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're saying you want to stick with javascript because you don't think jQuery can append URLs. This is not a real reason to just entirely ignore it. JQuery IS javascript, it's just a library. This means that you can just use vanilla javascript whenever you want it, for example, when you want to change the URL.

Now for your desired functionality. You can use the keyword `this` in your inline click event registrator (i.e. `onclick="printstuff()"`). Passing the `this` variable will allow you to use the clicked element in the click handler. So change `onclick="printStuff()"` to `onclick="printStuff(this)"`. Now in your function you can just use this instead of srcElement, and make sense.

### OR INSTEAD USE JQUERY LIKE THE REST OF THE WORLD

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
     $("#selwall).children("li").on("click", function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var category = "sellwall"; //probably want to store this into a data-category arrtibute somewhere (maybe in the id=sellwall ul)

          var imgClass = $(this).attr('class'); //preferably use data-img_id or something too (i.e. dont use classes and id's to store data you need somewhere else).
          $("#wallImg").attr('src', <url> with imgClass and category>);
     });
})
```

So I'd recommend using jQuery (since you're a javascript novice too, dont learn bad stuff, just learn how to program well right away) and using the data-attribute paradigm, look it up on the internet. Use it to store the URL parts you want to use.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I've amended your code with your recommendations (using data attributes instead of classes) as well as trying to pull the `imgCat` variable from the data attribute assigned to the parent of the element clicked. However the code now no longer works and I'm not sure why. I've read up on JQuery syntax and can't find anything wrong.

https://jsfiddle.net/s1my2mm8/

Comment: I've updated your jsfiddle, you were still using the "onclick", and you hadn't selected the javascript with jQuery library (console was showing "$ is not defined", $ is the jQuery object). I've also updated the way you're registering your clickevent. I changed your li's classes to "paint" so that you can register the click event to elements with the "paint" class, there is no need to have different classes for each li, so you shouldn't!
https://jsfiddle.net/s1my2mm8/4/

Comment: You've been a great assistance. I'm getting the hang of JQuery now.

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes to your script to make script work and get the parent id and class of the current element.

```js
function printStuff(srcElement) {
        var imgCategory = srcElement.parentNode;
        var imgClass = srcElement.className;

        document.getElementById("wallImg").src="http://testurl.co.uk/media/gbu0/" + imgCategory.getAttribute('id') + imgClass + ".png";
  
  alert(document.getElementById("wallImg").src);
  
  
  var url = 'testurl.com/paint-selection&selWall='+imgClass+'&selDoor='+ imgCategory.getAttribute('id');
  
  alert(url);

    }
```

```html
<div id="holder">
    <img id="wallImg" src="/testpath/selwall/nopaint.jpg">
</div>

<div id="options">
    <ul id="selWall">
        <li class="bluepaint" onclick="printStuff(this)"><strong>Blue</strong></li>
        <li class="redpaint" onclick="printStuff(this)"><strong>Red</strong></li>
        <li class="greenpaint" onclick="printStuff(this)"><strong>Green</strong></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```